# How do I make shapes (diagonal line, inverted triangle) using python?

Tags: python, shapes

Using this starting point:

```
size_in = input('Please enter the size: ')
size = int(size_in)
char = input('Please enter the drawing character: ')
print('')
row = 1
```

I've figured out how to make a square:

```
while row <= size:
    col = 1
    while col <= size:
        print(char, '', end = '')
        col = col + 1
    print('')
    row = row + 1
print('')
```

And a triangle:

```
row = 1
while row <= size:
    col = 1
    while col <= row:
        print (char, '', end = '') 
        col = col + 1
    print ('') 
    row = row + 1
print ('')
```

But I can't figure out a diagonal

```
X
 X
  X
   X
    X
```

Or a reverse triangle

```
xxxxx
 xxxx
  xxx
   xx
    x
```

The best I've come up with for the reverse triangle is:

```
row = 1
while row <= size:
    col = size - row + 1
    while col <= row:
        print (' ',)
        col = col + 1
    col = 0
    while col <= size-row:
        print (char, '', end = '') 
        col = col + 1
    row = row + 1
    print ('')
print ('')
```

But even that is  not quiet right, it's just flipped and has extra spaces. I cannot figure out how to do these.

Comment: The first `''` in your print statement has no effect. This `print(char, '', end = '')` prints the same as `print(char, end = '')`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `while` loop and a lot of extra operations. Just utilize the `range` function and correctly use the `start`, `end` and `step` arguments.

```
In [26]: for i in range(10, 0, -1):
             print((' ' * (10-i)) + (i * '+'))
   ....:     
++++++++++
 +++++++++
  ++++++++
   +++++++
    ++++++
     +++++
      ++++
       +++
        ++
         +

In [27]: 

In [27]: for i in range(10, 0, -1):
             print((' ' * (10-i)) + '+')
   ....:     
+
 +
  +
   +
    +
     +
      +
       +
        +
         +
```

Still, from an algorithmic perspective, all you need to print such shapes is starting from the highest level and counting down, then add space to the leading of each line in a reverse manner (from lowest level to the top level).